# Binding drawing a rectangle with the data in the textField, JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

How to correctly use the `widthProperty()` for data from  `textField`?

```
 widthRectangle.textProperty().bindBidirectional(rectangleObj.getWidthRectangleValue());
 rectangle.widthProperty().bind(rectangleObj.getWidthRectangleValue());
```

The above does not work. Maybe I'll find somewhere how to use it properly?

Edit:

```
public class RectangleObj {


    private StringProperty  widthRectangleValue  = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty  heightRectangleValue = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty getWidthRectangleValue(){
        return widthRectangleValue;
    }

    public void setWidthRectangleValue(StringProperty widthRectangleValue){
        this.widthRectangleValue = widthRectangleValue; 
    }


    public StringProperty getHeightRectangleValue(){
        return heightRectangleValue;
    }

    public void setHeightRectangleValue(StringProperty heightRectangleValue){
        this.heightRectangleValue = heightRectangleValue;   
    }
}
```

.

```
public class ControllerParametersForRectangle implements Initializable {


    @FXML
    Rectangle rectangle;

    @FXML
    TextField widthRectangle;

    @FXML
    TextField heightRectangle;

    RectangleObj rectangleObj = new RectangleObj();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        widthRectangle.textProperty().bindBidirectional(rectangleObj.getWidthRectangleValue());
        rectangle.widthProperty().bind(rectangleObj.getWidthRectangleValue());


    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I do not know what to make substitute to `bind()`

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Are we supposed to just telepathically know what `rectangleObj` is, and what `getWidthRectangleValue()` returns? Please take some time to read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not bind the value to a `StringProperty`. Use a [`TextFromatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) to convert the `TextField`'s text to another type instead.

Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100);

    StringConverter<Double> converter = new DoubleStringConverter();

    TextField xTextField = new TextField();
    TextFormatter<Double> xFromatter = new TextFormatter<>(converter);
    xTextField.setTextFormatter(xFromatter);

    TextField widthTextField = new TextField();

    TextFormatter<Double> widthFromatter = new TextFormatter<Double>(converter);
    widthTextField.setTextFormatter(widthFromatter);

    xFromatter.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(rect.xProperty().asObject());
    widthFromatter.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(rect.widthProperty().asObject());

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(10, xTextField, widthTextField, new Pane(rect)), 500, 500);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```